# Apply a resource for each provider - Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create an *aws_ssm_parameter* in 2 regions from within 1 resource block as I need the writer endpoint in both eu-central-1 and eu-west-1 available from SSM.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "primary_writer_endpoint" {
  name      = "/aurora/${var.environment}-${var.service_name}-primary-cluster/writer-endpoint"
  type      = "String"
  value     = aws_rds_cluster.primary.endpoint
  overwrite = true
}


resource "aws_ssm_parameter" "primary_writer_endpoint_replica_region" {
  name      = "/aurora/${var.environment}-${var.service_name}-primary-cluster/writer-endpoint"
  type      = "String"
  value     = aws_rds_cluster.primary.endpoint
  overwrite = true

  provider = aws.replica
}
```

as I declared 2 providers:

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "eu-central-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "replica"
  region = "eu-west-1"
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this, e.g. for each provider, or create a map of the providers?

Would be great to do this cleaner.

Comment: Sadly, there is no way to dynamically specify provider and aliases.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. Thanks for the swift reply @Marcin.